# ios Tile based View Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, windows-8, tile

I am working on a iOS app where the UI needs to be a "Tile Based" - Think Windows-8

When the App is launched - a "Home Screen" comes up with six tiles of various sizes - some are squares and some are rectangles.

When the user taps (or double taps) the view changes so that a more detail view is presented.  The detail view will have a "X" on the top right.  Clicking the "X" will bring the home screen back.

I am new to iOS - Is there a standard framework available to accomplish this?

Comment: no there is no standard framework available for this you have to do it programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use UICollectionView for that its available in iOS 6 and above.. Customise it according to your requirements. [Here is a tutorial that will help you.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) You can then customise it as you like just like a UITableVIew.